# Mini-book refuses to boot from usb ( LT41P )

Tags: boot, laptop, usb, gateway

I have this mini laptop, a Gateway LT41P. For whatever reason, This laptop refuses to boot from usb. I've created several working usb boot sticks, and have used it to install various OS (linux/windows) on my other laptop (without issue). But this laptop..

I've re-arranged the boot order to ensure my USB comes first. Nothing.
F12 Boot menu only displays a single windows hdd, nothing else.
No cd-tray, and no external drive to work with.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this damn thing won't boot from a USB. The option is clearly there, in the BIOS menu. But nothing comes up in the boot manager. Re-arranging the boot order with the USB at the top of the list, it simply skips like there is no usb inserted and boots right to windows.
I have stumbled across a few topics like [this one](http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/44995-gateway-lt41p-wont-boot-off-any-media-install-windows-8-7-a.html), so others are having the same issue but I can not find any solutions to the issue. I have read that gateway has done this with the newer books on purpose (locked the pre-installed os into the machine), but a quick phone call to customer support confirmed what I thought.

They have done no such thing with this model and there is no reason it should not boot to usb. They advised me against it (with acer recovery partion or whatever) but they told me what I already know. The option is there. For whatever reason, it just wants to be stubborn.

For such a tiny laptop this stupid thing is putting up one hell of a fight.

Specs are below. If anybody here sees something I've missed, Help is always appreciated.
-Thanks in advance.

**SPECS:**

```
CPU Type:    Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU n2805 @1.46GHz  
CPU Speed:    1.47GHz  

OS:    Windows 8  
Make:  GATEWAY    
Model: LT41P  
HDD:   Toshiba MQ01ABF032  
BIOS:  V2.07 x32
```

**(BIOS Settings):**

```
Secure boot:    DISABLED  
Network boot:   ENABLED  
F12 Boot menu:  ENABLED  
D2D Recovery:   ENABLED  
SATA Mode:      AHCI
```

Comment: Hey Ice ... Im having the same problem ... where you finally able to get it boot from USB ?

Answer (score 2):

Same device, I finally got it. Hopefully this helps someone.

LT41P Reformat / Boot via USB Solution:

1. Create a UEFI bootable USB using Rufus: GPT Partition, FAT32, 32Bit Windows Image (tried 64Bit):
   http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html
2. Insert above USB, restart device and press F2 to enter UEFI firmware
3. Disable Smartboot (Setting a password will allow you to disable).
4. Change the boot priority for USB HDD to be number 1, if your USB key is bootable / recognizable by the netbook you'll see it listed as - example: USB HDD Lexar 16 GB
5. If the above fails, enable 'Press F1 to select bootable device' and choose it that way
6. Install OS, remove USB when device reboots to continue install process

Looking at a fresh 32Bit Win 8.1 Pro install.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here you've an UEFI laptop. Be sure to create a compatible USB-key.

For Windows (starting from 7), use the Rufus utility : http://rufus.akeo.ie/ . For GNU/Linux, any decent and recent enough distribution should work, for example Fedora 20, Ubuntu 14.04…

Also, be sure to select a 64-bit ISO, as you probably have a 64-bit UEFI firmware which would (probably) not boot 32-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

When you go into the bios, check if there is a "Launch CSM" option in the boot options tab

If there is change it to always.

Also make sure that the boot menu is enabled.

When you save the changes and hit f12 at post, all your boot options should be available

Answer (score 0):

Download the updated BIOS here - Version 2.13
http://www.gateway.com/gw/en/CA/content/drivers-downloads

Product LT41P- 
Bios/Firmware-
Enable Legacy Mode  (Version 2.13)

Start Windows - Double Click download to begin firmware install.

Change UEFI Boot to Legacy boot in updated BIOS.

Comment: Any way to upgrade the BIOS on these machines without being able to start windows?

Comment: You need to have upgrade it from windows since the Bios installer is only for windows

Comment: This makes sense ...

Answer (score -1):

LDanger is wrong.  This model has a 64bit BIOS.  Running on 2.12 (because there is no With installed on the newly installed HD, we cannot put 2.1.3 on it yet).

IT WILL support a 64bit UEFI USB drive completely.   Looking at Windows 10 Enterprise installing as I type this 
 !

Answer (score -1):

SO I Got windows 7 Installed through a USB... I had wiped my hard drive before updating my bios... so I had to acquire a copy of windows 10 to install back onto this machine. It detects windows 8 and windows 10 through USB just fine. You must update your bios while having a version of windows installed, there is NO way to do it unless theres an OS. If you wiped your OS to install something different like I did, you must reinstall windows 8+ through USB, Update your bios, Set boot to Legacy mode, then you will be able to install windows 7  from a USB.

Answer (score -2):

This is based from my Experience! (Using Bootable USB Memory)

First, note that this mini laptop processor is x64 support, but the BIOS is 32 bit. for that reason never try to install a 64bit windows version if you do the system never recognize the USB Unit.

Prepare your USB unit with Rufus 2.2 as indicated below:

1) Select your windows ISO 32bit

2) This is not a UEFI based system, select MBR for UEFI in Partition 
type and system destination.

3) Always select FAT32 for this purpose in System Files.

4) Click on start button and wait the process finish.

Now, go to your mini laptop, press F2 to enter set up utility, select "Main" and go to 'F12 boot menu', here press Enter and select "Enable"
Save the parameters and re-boot your mini laptop and press F12 for invoke
booting menu.

in this moment you must able to see your Pendrive listed! Select this and begin windows installation.

I hope it work for all of you.